# Herencia en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, poo

Buenas, hemos visto un poco de programación orientada a objetos en javascript y nos han mandado hacer un ejercicio para utilizar herencia. Hay que calcular el volumen de un cilindro en el cual tenemos que utilizar el radio de un circulo de un ejercicio anteriormente. Pero no creo que lo este utilizando bien porque no me muestra nada.

**Código js calcular volumen:**

```
function calcularVolumenCilindro()
{
    var radio = Circulo.prototype.radio = getRadio();
    var altura = prompt("Introduce altura del cilindro: ")
    var volumen = volumenCilindro(radio,altura);
    document.write("El volumen del cilindro es: "+volumen);
}
```

**Código js volumenCilindro:**

```
function volumenCilindro(radio,altura)
{
    return Math.PI*radio*radio*altura;
}
```

Estoy utilizando la forma correcta de llamar al método getRadio() de la clase de otro ejercicio?

Comment: No lo estás usando bien, eso seguro, pero sería mejor que incluyeras en la pregunta el código de la clase circulo para darte una mejor respuesta

Comment: ¿Están en el mismo archivo o son archivos distintos?

Comment: Son archivos distintos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta.

No estás usando de forma correcta. Hay una parte del código que no tiene sentido:

```
var radio = Circulo.prototype.radio = getRadio();
```

Si `getRadio` es un método de la clase `Circulo`, entonces para llamarlo simplemente debes hacer, suponiendo que has creado un objeto de dicha clase:

```
var circulo = new Circulo(...)
var radio = circulo.getRadio()
```

---

### Solución "Moderna"

Puedes usar la nueva sintaxis de `Clase`.

En este ejemplo utilizo `getters` y `setters`, pero puedes usar métodos de clase si te es más cómodo.

```js
class Circulo {
  constructor(radio) {
    this._radio = radio
  }
  
  get radio () { return this._radio }
  set radio(radio) { this._radio = radio }
  
  get area() { return Math.PI * (this.radio**2) }
}

const circulo = new Circulo(10)

console.log(circulo.area)

class Cilindro extends Circulo {

  constructor(radio, altura) {
    super(radio)
    this._altura = altura
  }
  
  get altura() { return this._altura }
  set altura(altura) { this._altura = altura }
  
  get volumen() { return this.area * this.altura }

}

const cilindro = new Cilindro(10, 10)

console.log(cilindro.volumen)
```

**NOTA** El operador exponencial ([`**`](https://github.com/rwaldron/exponentiation-operator)) forma parte del estándar desde la versión ES2016(ES7).

Comment: tome su like buen hombre